# Are two duration sequences related?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I've segmented a video using two methods: One by listening to it (audio content) and one by watching it (visual content). Therefore, I have two sequences of segments.

From the audio analysis I have sections and subsections like this: 
From 7:02 to 7:54 the professor talked about "different types of attention systems", which breaks as follows: From 7:02 to 7:17 she said she's going to explain what ADHD means. ... 
From 7:54 to 9:15 the professor gave examples for "automatic attention".

From the video analysis I have, for example: From 7:04 to 7:18 the professor was shown. From 07:18 to 07:26 a slide was shown, from 07:26 to 07:36 the professor was shown, and so on.

So, I have two sequences of time segments (where the audio one, by content analysis, can be broken to smaller time segments). What I want to know is whether these sequences are related. Is there a synchronization, perhaps the view of the professor (left profile/ full body/ from afar) or slide are synchronized with the rhythm of the content, or is this random?

Comment: I don't think there is any simple answer to this.

Comment: It is a rather vaque question. For the visual part, I learned I could classify it into 2 categories: professor VS slide. (Maybe later there will be audience, etc). So it a time-series of 0s and 1s of different time length. However, audio segments look all unique. It is not even clear what kind of relation you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you, @Alexey Burnakov, for your comment. The video sequences are "typed" - "Professor shown pointing at the blackboard", "Professor left profile", "Professor from afar", "Audience", "Slide A", "Slide B" and so on. The audio segments are classified as major topic and subtopics by content analysis. I want to extract information about the relations between the video and the audio. For example, "whenever a slide is shown" (visual) "five to two seconds before the slide appears" "a major section starts" (audio).

Comment: @Avi, that is still rather difficult problem because of this: "The audio segments are classified as major topic and subtopics by content analysis." What I can recommend is to disjoint the analysis over different topics/subtopics. Let's say there are 5 major topics. You can get video timeseries sequences which are typed for each of the 5 topics. After that you can get an idea of the sort: "Whether there is a certain common pattern in video sequences *independent* of the topic." Let's say for all 5 topics there is a sequence: prof.left -> prof.right -> blackboard (very roughly).